# how to create joomla 2.5 quick installer package?

Tags: joomla

I have seen the quick joomla installer package from others theme development websites. I want to create the same file so that i can give my files to clients and he will easily install the joomla with ready made dummy content.
Thanks

Comment: All you need to do is take the Joomla package and replace the `.sql` file that gets executed with your own if the "*install sample data*" is selected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will explain more in depth as my comment was a little vague.

1. Joomla 2.5 package
2. You will see in **installation\sql\mysql** a file called **sample_data.sql**. Download a copy of your database and replace the file stated above with your one. Make sure you give it the same name.
3. Open your **sample_data.sql** and you will see a query to create a table and it's columns like so....**CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `#__assets`** ...replace this with: **TRUNCATE `#__categories`;**. Be sure to do this for each one you see.
4. Copy your template folder from your site to the **tempplates** folder in the new Joomla package.
5. Zip everything up and you're good to go

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Please see this detailed article:

http://www.joomlabamboo.com/blog/tutorials/create-your-own-joomla-installer